# Adding MS Outlook email box to the AAD Users after migration domain to Azure

Tags: azure, outlook, dns, azure-active-directory, email

I migrated my domain management from webio.pl to MS Azure [following this tutorial.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain)

After I created the `mydomain.net` domain in AAD, I created two new AAD users:

1. `noreply@mydomain.net.`
   which I want to use to send confirmation emails by my web app.
2. `admin@mydomain.net`
   with all the possible AAD permissions. I created this account because I found that I cannot log in to the 
   https://admin.microsoft.com as it threw an error when I was trying to use `@hotmail` account that I should use work or school account instead.

Now when I log in to the office 365 portal with `noreply@mydomain.net`, I can see this:[image]

So there's no Outlook icon or other icons for free versions of MS Office apps like OneNote or Excel.

I also tried to check if I can log in to the `noreply@mydomain.net` email on my cell phone Outlook app, but I'm getting "Log-In Error, The connection to your email server timed out. Please check your email settings."

The question is, what should I do to apply the email box for the accounts I created under the `@mydomain.net` domain?
Cheers

Comment: Have you checked - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/change-email-address?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity yea I've just checked this and the stuff which this documentation has I already achieved. I'm able to login with my user@mydomain.net with the AAD however I don't have access to the email box, so I cannot send and retrieve emails. Not sure if I just need to purchase a licence for my account for the Office 365 as is no longer free if used under own domain?

Comment: Is the issue fixed on your side?

Comment: So I found that these licenses are not that cheap. I'm actually working on a side project which is not even in beta state so it would be just stupid paying for the license to only have an email address with own domain. So, for now, I'm using my own business Gmail account which is free, and maybe when I release the beta I'll think about buying the license for support@mydomain.net. I'm rely surprised that there is no free option provided by Microsoft to have like only one email address under own domain for testing purposes only..

Comment: I want to investigate this https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/domain-authentication/ first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, yes. after [changing your email address to use your custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/change-email-address?view=o365-worldwide), you still need an Exchange license for sending or receiving emails for the custom domain users. For more information, refer to [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/azure-ad-sync-and-shared-mailboxes/39e0c2ee-b2ef-4892-8d9e-64d5da592c76).

[image]